# Why does cmd DIR search include files that start with the 3 searched letters but then differ?

Tags: cmd, directory

If in a directory I have two files, `test.pro` and `test.properties`, and I run `dir /s *.pro` to find all files with the .pro extension, it lists both files. However, when I run `dir /s *.pr`, it lists neither. Why does searching for a three-letter file extension list files with extensions that start with the three letters? How can I search for ONLY .pro files using dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command **DIR** lets the file system search for file system entries (file names, directory names, reparse points (links)) matching the wildcard pattern `*.pro` in long name or in short 8.3 name on short name management also enabled for the file system of current drive.

The short file name of `test.pro` is `TEST.PRO`.
The short file name of `test.properties` is `TEST~1.PRO`.

Therefore the wildcard pattern `*.pro` matches `test.pro` and `TEST~1.PRO` displayed with long file name `test.properties`.

The wildcard pattern `*.pr` does not match with the two file names because of the file extension is `pro` respectively `properties` and not just `pr`. The wildcard pattern `*.pr?` would also find the file names `test.pro` and `TEST~1.PRO` displayed with long file name `test.properties`.

There can be used `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R . *.pro` to find recursively in current directory and all its subdirectories files with file extension `.pro` not matching file names with a longer file extension beginning with `pro` because of **WHERE** applies the wildcard pattern only on long file names.

**DIR** and also **FOR** use the Windows file I/O function which directly searches with the wildcard pattern `*.pro` for suitable file system entries. **WHERE** uses the Windows file I/O function to search for `*` to get a list of long names of all file system entries and then applies the wildcard pattern itself on each string returned by the file system. For that reason the usage of the wildcard pattern `*.pro` returns a positive result only on `test.pro` and not on `test.properties` on using **WHERE**.